# Dichromate-thio titration

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration

Can dichromate in acidic media be titrated directly with buffered thiosulfate solution using $\ce{H2O2}$ as an external indicator instead of  using $\ce{KI}$ which is a standard procedure?

$\ce{H2O2}$ is used as an external indicator because dichromate in the presence of excess acid reacts with $\ce{H2O2}$ to yield a transient blue color due to formation of $\ce{CrO5}$.